# Find UILocalNotification in scheduledLocalNotifications array without for loop?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Currently I am looping through all of my scheduled local notifications to find a "match" based upon a value in the userInfo dictionary object. This is seemingly very slow when I have 30+ local notifications set. Is there a way to access an individual local notification without traversing through the array?

Here is what I have:

```
NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]     scheduledLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification *row = nil;
for (row in notificationArray) {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = row.userInfo;
            NSString *identifier = [userInfo valueForKey:@"movieTitle"];
            NSDate *currentAlarmDateTime = row.fireDate;
if([identifier isEqualToString:myLookUpName]) {
 NSLog(@"Found a match!");
}
}
```

Here is what I want:

```
NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]     scheduledLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification *row = " The row in notificationArray where [userInfo valueForKey:@"movieTitle"]=myLookUpName" ;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be able to use predicates for this, but I have not tested it:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userInfo.movieTitle = %@", myLookUpName];
```

And then use that predicate to filter the array and grab the first element:

```
UILocalNotification *row = [[notificationArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Again, this is untested and may not work.

**EDIT**

If that doesn't work, you can use a test block:

```
UILocalNotification *row = [[notificationArray objectsAtIndexes:[notificationArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return [[[obj userInfo]valueForKey:@"movieTitle"] isEqualToString:myLookUpName];
}]]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what is going on in the test block code? I tried to "copy and paste it" in to my code but it yields an error:  Incompatible block pointer types sending 'id (^)(id, NSUInteger, BOOL *)' to parameter of type 'BOOL (^)(id, NSUInteger, BOOL *)'

Comment: @Eric: Not sure why you are getting that error. http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/20/being-a-blockhead/ may be helpful in determining the problem.

Comment: Coming in real late here, but for anyone else who stumbles across this great answer but is thrown by the typo in the code, try this:

```
UILocalNotification *row = [[notificationArray objectsAtIndexes:[notificationArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return [[[obj userInfo] valueForKey:@"movieTitle"] isEqualToString:myLookUpName];
}]]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: @andy: Fixed. Thanks.